# TRUE and FALSE as boolean versus same as characters

Tags: r

Could you elaborate on, what is going on here:

```
a = "TRUE"
b = TRUE
a
#[1] "TRUE"
b
#[1] TRUE
str(a)
#chr "TRUE"
str(b)
#logi TRUE
a == b
#[1] TRUE
```

This is only `TRUE` for the string `"TRUE"` in that e.g.:

```
"STRING" == TRUE
#[1] FALSE
```

So it is not because a non-empty string is `TRUE` like en e.g. Perl, therefore I would have expected `TRUE == "TRUE"` would yield `FALSE`?

Comment: From `?Comparison`: _"If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw._"

Comment: @lukeA : I see, thank you for your answer. This is imho an annoying feature, I would prefer being punished if I was trying to compare in-comparable entities...

Comment: It is part of a general principle in R that things are promoted to the most general representation when incompatible types are mixed in an operation. I think it fits to the fact that R is a dynamic and functional language, more like Lisp, than the C family.

Comment: Just a quick-add: It can be exemplified like so: typing `c(1,"1",TRUE,"TRUE")` at the R-prompt will yield: `[1] "1"    "1"    "TRUE" "TRUE"`

Comment: Shouldn't someone post an answer so the question that can be marked as a solution and be "retired"?

Comment: R tries to be as accommodating as possible, and programmer should keep that in mind. No need for a whip on every corner. :)

Comment: @lukeA : I think you answered the question nicely, so you should be credited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote `?Comparison` in the help files:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

R is automatically coercing the values down resulting in

```
"TRUE" == TRUE
# [1] TRUE
1 == TRUE
# [1] TRUE
```

etc.

Comment: Note also that "TRUe" !=TRUE  - just another example that makes it clear what is happening.